# live555 integration into iPhone app for streaming RTMP or RTSP video to iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, stream, rtsp, rtmp

Does anyone have any code or can point me in the right direction for integrating live555
into an iPhone app. I know that you can build the live555 C++ library for iOS but am not 
sure about the actual integration of this at a code level.

A link to a tutorial or some code would be wonderful :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/) here
2. Unpack it somevhere (in my case /Volumes/OSX/live)
3. find config.iphoneos an open it using text editor
4. change LINK_OPTS to

   LINK_OPTS =             -L. -arch armv7 --sysroot=$(SDK) -L$(SDK)/usr/lib/system
   and

   IOS_VERSION =       6.0 (your current sdk)
5. navigate in terminal to live555 dir (my case cd /Volumes/OSX/live)
6. then run in terminal ./genMakefiles iphoneos
7. run in terminal make

Comment: I tried this. And, i got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13928131/940096) issue only