# Live555 framework generation error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4.5, live555

I'm trying to build the framework for **Live555** library.
I got the library file from [here](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/) as per this [answer of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12896328/940096) I've tried multiple times to generate it as per that answer. It is simply giving the following error :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++ -c -Iinclude -I../UsageEnvironment/include -I../groupsock/include -I.  -DBSD=1 -O2 -DSOCKLEN_T=socklen_t -DHAVE_SOCKADDR_LEN=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fPIC -arch armv7 --sysroot=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk -Wall Media.cpp
make[1]: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Media.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I googled it for this issue. I got an [exact link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11369933/940096) with which an another user tried for this. At present my *[config.iphoneos](http://pastie.org/5546247)*

Has anyone faced this issue before? Kindly give me some idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you what the problem is.

Have a look in Terminal, do you actually have `g++` at this path? I do. It seems that you do not.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++